# Qué es el elemento Clearfix en un registro de búsquedas?

Tags: html, css

Estoy estudiando los divs conjuntamente con los containers, pero no entiendo cuando y por que se utiliza el elemento Clearfix en el contenido del resultado de una búsqueda. 
Me podrían poner algún ejemplo para poder ver sus cualidades, no me sirve el de bootstrap, ya que ese me lo he mirado y no entiendo bien.

Comment: Normalmente los elementos Clearfix se utilizan después de elementos flotados para limpiar el flots. El nombre lo puedes cambiar. No entiendo a que te refieres con _registro de búsquedas_

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats#The_background_of_floats

Comment: Bienvenido al stackoverflow, clearfix es algo relacionado a una técnica CSS, pero imagino que con "en un registro de búsqueda" se referirá algo que se puede dentro de un div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un *clearfix* es una forma en que un elemento borra automáticamente sus elementos secundarios, de modo que no necesita agregar marcas adicionales. Generalmente se usa en diseños flotantes donde los elementos se flotan para apilarse horizontalmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El *clearfix* es una forma de combatir el problema del contenedor de
>   altura cero para elementos flotantes

Por ejemplo:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Viejos browser que no soportan contenido vacío */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

O si no necesitás soporte para IE < 8, entonces esto también funciona:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Normalmente se haría algo como lo siguiente:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">Sidebar</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div> <!-- Clear the float -->
</div>
```

Pero con *clearfix* sería:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="float: left;" class="clearfix">Sidebar</div>
    <!-- No Clearing div! -->
</div>
```

---

Obtenido de una pregunta en SO EN: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Comment: Una pregunta, que pasaría si queremos poner div(contenedor) en horizontal, sería con overflow? Igual sería posible con float.

Comment: El atributo `overflow` es para mostrar o no la barra de scroll en horizontal o vertical.

Comment: Lo del clearfix es que he visto que cuando en amazon tu haces una busqueda de un producto. Los divs que almacenan los resultados de la busqueda estan todos agrupados por un clearfix; Eso que hace? que no se desordene?

Comment: Por lo general, lo que explico en la respuesta, es más gráfico con la imagen.